# Load my php script only once the page load

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am creating a shopping website where this it the page where product shows up.
now i want to add sorting functionality by color but issue comes when the page load only first mysql query run not any other this happens every time the page loads.

This php script create multiple div in row, what I want to do is run `$query` only once but when the page reload second time those div does not show up.
I want to this because I want to run other mysql query after the page reload.

```
<?php
//get rows query
$query = $db->query("SELECT pd.Product_Details_ID,pd.Slide_Photos,pd.rate,pm.Product_Name,pm.Product_ID,pm.gender from product_details as pd INNER JOIN product_master as pm ON pd.Product_ID=pm.Product_ID where pm.gender='$gender' ");
if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        ?>
        <div class="col-sm-4 ">
            <div class="productBox">
                <div class="productImage clearfix">
                    <img src="<?php echo $row["Slide_Photos"]; ?>" alt="products-img">
                    <div class="productMasking">
                        <ul class="list-inline btn-group" role="group">
                            <li><a class="btn btn-default btn-wishlist"><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="temp.php?action=addToCart&Product_Details_ID=<?php echo $row["Product_Details_ID"]; ?>&gender=<?php echo $row["gender"]; ?>" class="btn btn-default" data-toast data-toast-type="success" data-toast-position="topRight" data-toast-icon="icon-circle-check" data-toast-title="Product" data-toast-message="successfuly added to cart!" class="btn btn-default"   onclick="alert('product added successfully.')"><i class="fa fa-shopping-basket"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a class="btn btn-default" href="product_info.php?Product_Details_ID=<?php echo $row["Product_Details_ID"]; ?>"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="productCaption clearfix">
                    <a href="single-product.html">
                        <h5><?php echo $row['Product_Name']; ?> <?php echo $row["Product_Details_ID"]; ?></h5>
                    </a>
                    <h3><?php echo $row["rate"]; ?></h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    <?php }
} else { ?>
    <p>Product(s) not found.....</p>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: show your jquey/javascript code

Comment: there is no jquery or javascript code right now\

Comment: Are you setting `$gender` every time you load the page?

Comment: no it comes from other page when ever this page is called

Comment: How do you get the value of `$gender`?

Comment: the value sent from other page who call this page anytime with anchor tag

Comment: do you get the value of `$gender` when you load page once, twice or thrice?

Comment: once  only when the page is called

Comment: Once the value of `$gender` will be set so the query will return some data then the value `$gender` will not set so it will return null so the the query will not return anything

Comment: how can i can i do smoething like this

Comment: You have to keep setting `$gender` when every time page loads

Comment: yes that worked thank you